# How can I add a new vertex in blender 2.8?

Tags: vertices

When I click <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to add a vertex, nothing happens.

How can I add a vertex in 2.8?

For now I merged mesh vertices at the center and extruded from that.

However I am not sure if this would cause any problems.

Comment: Ctrl + rmb does what you're looking for. It's changed since they updated to left click select.

Answer (score 5):

It's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> now. You could always create a face and delete the other three vertices.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be anymore, it isn't working

Comment: it's ctrl+lmb on mine in edit mode. try that and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 4):

I have just spent the better part of the past few minutes trying to figure out this same thing

There are a few ways to achieve this:

1. Select *two* vertices, press <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> and select `subdivide` to add a new vertex between them
2. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> if using <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> select (**note**: make sure you are in wireframe mode, as the new vertex may be hidden by your mesh)
3. Select an existing vertex next to where you want the new vertex and do one of the following:

   - <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to create a new disconnected vertex, then press <kbd>g</kbd> to drag it wherever you want
   - <kbd>e</kbd> to extrude a connected vertex and again <kbd>g</kbd> to drag it wherever you want

Comment: Thank you for the edit @cegaton! I was not aware of that markdown.

Comment: I use one of the scripts from this post: [Button to insert <kbd></kbd> for users](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388/button-to-insert-kbd-kbd-for-users/390#390)